# Finding consecutive edges linking certain nodes in graph

Tags: graph-theory, networkx

I have a road network graph that can be represented simplistically as the figure below.
Most nodes have two neighbors, but some have three, meaning they are "intersections", or "crossroads". These are represented in red in the figure.

I want to find every sequence of consecutive edges directly linking two red nodes (by "directly" I mean, not passing through an intermediate red node).

Currently, I can find the red nodes like this:

```
crossroad_nodes = [node for node in graph.nodes() if len(graph.edges(node)) > 2]
```

But I don't know how to assemble a sequence of `networkx` commands to do what I want.

Desired output would be something like

```
print segments
> [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,5,6,2,4,7],[9,8,7,6,3,2],...] # list of lists of nodes or node indices.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shortest_path` function to find the paths, and then check to make sure afterwards that it does not pass through another crossroad.

Here is one way to do the check using sets and looking between all pairwise combinations of `crossroad_nodes`.

```
import itertools as it
import sets
#import networkx as nx

c_s = set(crossroad_nodes)
for i in it.combinations(crossroad_nodes,2):
    path = nx.shortest_path(G,source=i[0],target=i[1])
    #check to make sure path does not pass through another crossroad node
    if len((c_s - set(i)) & set(path)) == 0:
        print i,path
```

---

Here is a full reproducible example for a constructed graph.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.grid_graph([3,6])
pos = nx.spectral_layout(G)

for i in range(1,5):
    G.remove_edge((0, i),(1, i))
    G.remove_edge((1, i),(2, i))

#example using corners
crossroad_nodes = [(0, 0),(2, 0),(0, 5),(2, 5)]
oth = [i for i in G.nodes() if i not in crossroad_nodes]

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=oth,node_color='black')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=crossroad_nodes)
#nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)

#find the paths between our nodes of interest
import itertools as it
import sets

c_s = set(crossroad_nodes)
for i in it.combinations(crossroad_nodes,2):
    path = nx.shortest_path(G,source=i[0],target=i[1])
    #check to make sure path does not pass through another crossroad node
    if len((c_s - set(i)) & set(path)) == 0:
        print i,path
```

Comment: Also note this will fail with an error if the graph is not connected. If that is the case, you will have to check to see if the two nodes are connected first using the `has_path` function.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about this specific implementation for my case (which I didn't state completely anyway), you are right, `shortest_path` is the method I was looking, and [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) was the terminology I didn't have yet.